# how to use REGEXP with defined parameter in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex, stored-procedures

i have an stored procedure like below:

```
SET temp_Today = SUBSTR(( NOW() + 0) FROM 3 FOR 6);
SET temp_LastIdDoc = CONCAT(temp_Today,temp_IdAgency);
SELECT NumDoc FROM tbldocument WHERE NumDoc REGEXP '^temp_LastIdDoc';
```

i know it's wrong because it searches for NumDoc that begins with 'temp_LastIdDoc'. how can i use temp_LastIdDoc as parameter in this query?
and another question is that how can i limit chars that come after it to 4 chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way -

```
SET temp_LastIdDoc = CONCAT('^', temp_Today, temp_IdAgency);
SELECT NumDoc FROM tbldocument WHERE NumDoc REGEXP temp_LastIdDoc;
```

Comment: and how can i continue it just with 4 chars?

Answer (score 2):

String starts with variable `temp_LastIdDoc` and ends with 4 chars (`....$`)

```
SELECT NumDoc FROM tbldocument 
  WHERE NumDoc REGEXP CONCAT('^',temp_LastIdDoc,'....$');
```

Comment: can i use'_' instead of '.'? what's their different?

Comment: You should use ".". [REGEXP manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)